# How to re-enable/re-bind jQuery UI Sortable after $.unbind?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

`$('div.something').sortable(options)` works fine, but breaks after `$('div.something').unbind();`. Attempting to re-run `$('div.something').sortable(options);` or `$('div.something').sortable('refresh');` after `$('div.something').unbind();` does not help.

I am using $.unbind to deactivate/un-initiate a plugin by removing the events from the element that the plugin is being applied on, however this technique is having an adverse effect in that it is breaking $.sortable. **Any ideas on how re-activate sortable?**

I am using the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: What are you trying to deactivate, exactly? Making call to unbind all event handlers is a somewhat dangerous operation since you are giving up control of what you are unbinding.

Comment: @RubenInfante I'm unbinding a plugin (lots of jQuery code + backbone) that does too many things such that it is complicated to write a "destroy" equivalent to go through and properly clean out its code. Other events like click work fine after the unbind, but sortable is giving me trouble.

Comment: do you want to disable `sortable` plugin or want to disable all events from the element

Comment: It is difficult to isolate the problem when we cannot see the code that is being affected (the plug-in) by the call to `.unbind()`. In any case, you may want to try calling `.sortable( "destroy" )` prior to calling `.unbind()`. Then you should be able to recreate the sortable with the methods you initially stated.

Comment: @RubenInfante calling `$.sortable('destroy')` before `$.unbind` and the `$.sortable(options)` after `$.unbind` fixes the problem. Thank you! Please feel free to add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Making a call to `.sortable('destroy')` prior to calling `.unbind()` will completely remove the sortable feature from the element.

This ensures proper tear-down before performing the somewhat dangerous call to `.unbind()`, which removes all bound handlers on the element. Then, you can re-initialize the sortable feature.

```
// Initialization of the sortable feature
$('div.something').sortable(options);
...
// Remove the sortable feature to prevent bad state caused by unbinding all
$('div.something').sortable('destroy');
// Unbind all event handlers!
$('div.something').unbind();
...
// Re-initialize the sortable feature
$('div.something').sortable(options);
```

Comment: .sortable('destroy') is awesome. took me quite a bit to find it :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to deactivate the [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin I recommend using [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-destroy) method

```
$('div.something').sortable(options)//Activate
....
$('div.something').sortable('destroy')//Remove the plugin functionality
....
$('div.something').sortable(options)//Reactivate
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KxnHb/1/)

Comment: I am trying to re-active `$.sortable()` after `$.unbind()`. Problem resolved (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457292/how-to-re-enable-re-bind-jquery-ui-sortable-after-unbind#comment21871866_15457292). You had the right idea.

Comment: @Max looks like you added a reference my own answer